# 502 "failed_to_pick_backend" when using PSC backend with Classic Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-load-balancer, http-status-code-502

I'm working to see if I can connect an external Application LB to an internal passthrough LB in a different project via Private Service Connect.  The external LB side shows a good load balancer endpoint, and the publisher project shows a good PSC connection as well.  But when I send a test request, I get a 502 with this message in the logs: `failed_to_pick_backend`

Oddly, if I re-deploy the load balancer with the exact same configuration but non-classic, everything works fine and I can connect to the internal load balancer.  I checked the JSON ouptut for each deployment and they're exactly the same other than `loadBalancingScheme` is `EXTERNAL` for Classic and `EXTERNAL_MANAGED` for non-Classic, which is expected.

Are there any special gotchas or configurations needed for Classic?  Maybe the protocol or localityLbPolicy parameters need to be set a certain way?